# Add marker to google map after map is initialised

Tags: c#, javascript, wpf, google-maps-api-3

I’ve got a c# wpf project using a webbrowser control to host a google map. Note this is NOT an asp project.

If I add markers during the initialize routine they work. If I call the same routine later from c# using InvokeScript then it doesn’t work.

I’m hopeful of having a page where my c# code can add/remove/update markers as required by calling various javascript functions.

I'm not strong with javascript and I suspect there is something key that i'm not understanding.

Pertinent parts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com.mx/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language="es""></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var markersArray = [];
var gmap;

function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng([GLAT], [GLONG]);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: [ZOOM],
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

[MARKERLOCATIONS]

}

function AddMarker(Latitude, Longitude, Description) {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude, Longitude);

    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        position: latlng,
        map: gmap,
        title: Description,
        labelContent: "1",
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(7, 30),
        labelClass: "labels",
        labelInBackground: false
    });

</script>

<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</script>
```

I replace [GLAT], [GLONG] and [ZOOM] with actual co-ordinates and zoom. More on [LOCATIONS] shortly.

MarkerWithLabel is Gary Little’s code http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.8/src/markerwithlabel.js

If I replace [MARKERLOCATIONS] with the following I get my desired marker on the page

```
AddMarker(51.47,0,"Greenwich")
```

Repeating this statement with different co-ordinates gives me as many markers as I want.

If I remove [MARKERLOCATIONS] and instead in c# do the following, it doesn’t work (gmap is the wpf webbrowser):

```
gmap.LoadCompleted += new LoadCompletedEventHandler(gmap_LoadCompleted);

void gmap_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // Add markers
    foreach (Marker myM in ListMarker)
    {
        Object[] CallArgs = new Object[3];
        CallArgs[0] = myM.Latitude.ToString();
        CallArgs[1] = myM.Longitude.ToString();
        CallArgs[2] = myM.ShortDescription;
        object dummy = gmap.InvokeScript("AddMarker", CallArgs);
    }
}
```

For debugging purposes I put an alert in AddMarker and the values I pass in turn up; I also created a function to loop through the contents of markersArray:

```
function ReportGPS() {
    if (markersArray) {
        for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
            //remove the marker from the map
            alert(markersArray[i].toString());
        }
    }
}


public void Test()
{
    object dummy = gmap.InvokeScript("ReportGPS");
}
```

If I add say 5 markers, then ReportGPS gives me 5 alerts.

So it’s like they are simply not being added to the map. Again, if the AddMarker is called from the initialise function it works.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might be that you are calling the `AddMarker` function before the `initialize` function has been executed. I've got some code that is doing something very similar and I use C# to invoke my `initialize` function before invoking my `AddMarker` function.

Try removing the `initialze` call from `<body onload="initialize()">` and adding an `InvokeScript` function call to initialize the map.

```
void gmap_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    gmap.InvokeScript("initialize");

    // Add markers
    foreach (Marker myM in ListMarker)
    {
        Object[] CallArgs = new Object[3];
        CallArgs[0] = myM.Latitude.ToString();
        CallArgs[1] = myM.Longitude.ToString();
        CallArgs[2] = myM.ShortDescription;
        object dummy = gmap.InvokeScript("AddMarker", CallArgs);
    }
}
```